# Making a distinction between file not present and access denied while accessing s3 object via Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I have inherited the following code. This is part of CICD pipeline. It tries to get an object called "changes" from a bucket and does something with it. If it is able to grab the object, it sends a success message back to pipeline.  If it fails to grab the file for whatever reason, it sends a failure message back to codepipeline.

This "changes" file is made in previous step of the codepipeline. However, sometimes it is valid for this file NOT to exist (i.e. when there IS no change).

Currently, the following code makes no distinction if file simply does not exist OR some reason code failed to get it (access denied etc.)

Desired:
  I would like to send a success message back to codepipeline if file is simply not there.
  If there is access issue , then the current outcome of "failure' would still be valid.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I am not good enough with Javascript to have any ideas to try.

**RELEVANT PARTS OF THE CODE**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
const codePipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline();


// GET THESE FROM ENV Variables

const {
    API_SOURCE_S3_BUCKET: s3Bucket,
    ENV: env
} = process.env;


const jobSuccess = (CodePipeline, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        CodePipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            else { resolve(data); }
        });
    });
};

const jobFailure = (CodePipeline, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        CodePipeline.putJobFailureResult(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            else { resolve(data); }
        });
    });
};

// MAIN CALLER FUNCTION. STARTING POINT
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    try {
        // WHAT IS IN changes file in S3
        let changesFile = await getObject(s3, s3Bucket, `lambda/${version}/changes`);
        let changes = changesFile.trim().split("\n");
        console.log("List of Changes");
        console.log(changes);

        let params = { jobId };
        let jobSuccessResponse = await jobSuccess(codePipeline, params);
        context.succeed("Job Success");
    }
    catch (exception) {
        let message = "Job Failure (General)";
        let failureParams = {
            jobId,
            failureDetails: {
                message: JSON.stringify(message),
                type: "JobFailed",
                externalExecutionId: context.invokeid
            }
        };

        let jobFailureResponse = await jobFailure(codePipeline, failureParams);
        console.log(message, exception);
        context.fail(`${message}: ${exception}`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 should return an [error code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList) in the exception:

The ones you care about are below:

> - AccessDenied - Access Denied
> - NoSuchKey - The specified key does not exist.

So in your catch block you should be able to validate exception.code to check if it matches one of these 2.

Comment: Thank you for such quick answer!